# comparing two arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

To compare two strings in java I used following code

```
String ary[]={"man","john","su"};
String ary1[]={"john","man","su"};

if(Arrays.equals(ary,ary1)) {
    System.out.println("equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("not equal");
}
```

It prints "not equal",But this two arrays are having same values.

Indeed here the both arrays are same but values positions change.

How can I tell that this kind of arrays are same.

Comment: You should read the doc. It clearly states: _"In other words, the two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order"_ Which is not the case in your example. You may sort them first an then use it.

Comment: Sort first, then compare...

Comment: Define your own comparator after creating a collection from the values contained within?

Comment: Can there be duplicate elements in your base arrays?

Comment: If order of the elements does not matter then you may use a java.util.Set

Comment: Spin through the first array and put elements in a set.  Spin through the second and check for set membership.

Comment: @Hot Licks: that wouldn't deal with duplicate elements correctly (if that matters to the OP).

Comment: @JBNizet - You'd have to define how you wanted duplicates dealt with.  You could use a counting set, eg, to assure you had the same number of both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work.

```
    String ary[]={"man","john","su"};
    String ary1[]={"john","man","su"};
    boolean isEqual = true;
    if(ary.length != ary1.length) {
        System.out.println("not equal");
    } else {
        int countEquals = 0;
        ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(ary1) );
        for (String str : ary) {
            if (wordList.contains(str)) {
                countEquals++;
                wordList.remove(str);
            } else {
                isEqual = false;
                System.out.println("not equal");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isEqual) {
            System.out.println("equal");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The countEquals is useless I forgot to remove it. Just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you just try to see if they are equal, if this is true, just go with something like this:

```
boolean areEqual = Arrays.equals(Arrays.sort(arr1), Arrays.sort(arr2));
```

This is the standard way of doing it.

Doing so because like ZouZou states and as marked in the documentation:

> "Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same
>   number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
>   arrays are equal. In other words, two arrays are equal if they contain
>   the same elements in the same order"

Comment: The problem is that this will only work if elements of both arrays implement `Comparable`

Comment: Arrays.sort() returns void. This wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sets:

```
if (ary.length == ary1.length && new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ary)).equals(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ary1)))
```

---

Test code:

```
String ary[] = { "man", "john", "su" };
String ary1[] = { "john", "man", "su" };
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ary));
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ary1));
System.out.println(ary.length == ary1.length && set1.equals(set2));
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: If `ary` is `{ "man", "john", "man", "su" };`, then `ary` is not equals to `ary1`.

Comment: What you really want is a Bag, or Multiset: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @ZouZou OK then. I added some code for that case.

Comment: You can't add a test with the lenght. Assume now `String ary[] = { "man", "john", "su" ,"man"};
  String ary1[] = { "john", "man", "su" ,"john"};`. Still outputs true.

Comment: @ZouZou hmmm... it's starting to get fiddley

Answer (score 0):

```
String ary[] = { "man", "john", "su" };     
String ary1[] = { "man", "john", "su" };
boolean check = true;       

for(int i=0; i<ary.length; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<ary1.length; j++)
  {
    if(i == j)
    {
        if(!ary[i].equals(ary1[j]))
        {
            check = false;
        }
    }   
  }
}
```

This code may be help you. Good Luck.